# Placing Android Banner Ads over ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, banner-ads

I want to place two banner ads in my activity- one at the top, another on the bottom of the *screen*. I have **LinearLayout** as the main layout and it contains a **ScrollView** that is larger than the screen. If I put the following *XML* code at the end of the **ScrollView**, it goes out of the screen. Clearly it needs to be drawn on top of the **ScrollView**. How can I do that?

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by putting the following code to your design file.

Change your Xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="DemoActivity">


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></ScrollView>


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It works. I am new to android development. I would like an explanation about the height and weight of the scrollview (the values you used here).

Comment: @Shuvo Sarker Whenever we need to stick any views to top or bottom and assign the rest of the height to other main views then at that time we will give the weight property so it will automatically occupied all the rest space for own. and that time we will give height to "0" because when you set weight then there is no roll of height for that view.